# Should I be able to ping the DNS in WSL

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

in WSL2 Ubuntu under Windows 10 I see this when calling

cat /etc/resolv.conf

```
# This file was automatically generated by WSL. To stop automatic generation of this file, add the following entry to /etc/wsl.conf:
# [network]
# generateResolvConf = false
nameserver 172.19.80.1
```

those fail

```
ping 172.19.80.1
ping 1.1.1.1
ping 8.8.8.8
```

I can ping the global dns servers from the windows host through my VPN

Would it be expected from the linux wsl guest if not how to fix that ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is a Hyper-V issue.

Disabling and restarting the PC did solve the issue.